# How to find eigenvectors of a nxn matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be the $n\times n$ matrix with a 1 in every entry. How to find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $A$? We cannot find them by the ordinary method using characteristic polynomials, right? Then what shall we do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that such matrix is a projection (with dilation) onto the one dimensional subspace spanned by $\vec v=(1,1,...,1)$.

Comment: So you mean T(T(x))=T(x) for all x in span {(1,1,1...,1)}?

Comment: So the eigenvalues are 0 and 1?

Comment: @Edwards Yes exactly!

Comment: @gimusi NO! The eigenvalue is NOT $1$! The matrix, multiplied by the vector of all ones, produces $n$ times the same vector!

Comment: @5xum ops sorry of course it is $n$! Thanks to have pointed out my dumb and inattentive quick answer! :)

Comment: @Edwards sorry I was inattentive! of course $T(x)=nx$ for $x \in span {(1,1,1...,1)}$ ;) then eigenvalues are $\lambda_1= n$ and the others $\lambda_i=0$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Comment: @Edwards indeed it is a projection with dilation by n on the subspace.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix has rank $1$, so its null space has dimension $n-1$. If $n>1$, this means $0$ is an eigenvalue with geometric multiplicity $n-1$, so its algebraic multiplicity is $\ge n-1$.

On the other hand, $n$ is an eigenvalue of the matrix (why?), so its algebraic multiplicity is $\ge 1$.

Therefore $0$ has algebraic multiplicity $n-1$ and $n$ has algebraic multiplicity $1$, because the sum of the algebraic multiplicities is $n$; no other eigenvalue can exist.

The characteristic polynomial is thus $\det(A-\lambda I)=(0-\lambda)^{n-1}(n-\lambda)$. (This also holds for $n=1$, of course, because $(0-\lambda)^0=1$.)